# How can I efficiently select 100 random JPG files from a directory (including subdirs) in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory-structure

I have a very large directory of files and folders. Currently, I scan the entire directory for JPGs and store them in a list. This is really slow due to the size of the directory. Is there a faster, more efficient way to do this? Perhaps without scanning everything?

My directory looks like this:

```
/library/Modified/2000/[FolderName]/Images.JPG
/library/Modified/2001/[FolderName]/Images.JPG
/library/Modified/2002/[FolderName]/Images.JPG
/library/Modified/2003/[FolderName]/Images.JPG
/library/Modified/2004/[FolderName]/Images.JPG
...
/library/Modified/2012/FolderName/Images.JPG
```

Thanks

Comment: Depends. What does the directory layout look like?

Comment: I don't know your constraints, but you could perhaps use the `updatedb` command once and then use the output of `locate /library/Modified` as the input for your program.

Comment: Since it seems to be mostly historic data, you could save the list for previous years to a file so that it only has be to scanned once, then append a folder scan for the current year.

Answer (score 2):

See [Generator Tricks for System Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/index.html) for a bunch of neat stuff. But specifically, see the [gen-find](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/genfind.py) example. This is as efficient as you are going to get, without making a bunch of assumptions about your file structure layout.

Comment: And how does this help when randomness comes into play?

Comment: @ms4py what kind of randomness? Hardware failure?

Comment: See the title! How do you want to select 100 items randomly from a generator?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you application is the only one changing directory and that you have control over the directory names/structure and that you have to do the operation described in your question more than once:

Rename all the files once so you can access them in predictable order. Say, give all files numeric name from 1 to N (where N is the number of files in directory) and have a special file ".count" which will hold the N for each directory. Then access them directly with their names generated by random generator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the slowness occurs, but to scan directories and files I found it much faster the dump the directories/files into a text file first using a batch file then get python to read the file. This worked well on our server system with 7 servers and many thousands of directories.
Python could, of course, run the batch file.